# How to shutdown WAR/EAR programmatically

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, web-applications, jersey

Is there any way to stop a WAR/EAR programmatically?

I need to stop the application deployment if something goes wrong during the startup /config process.

If possible the solution should be cross server compatible, because our application must run in JBoss AS 7 and Websphere 7/8.

Currently the application doesn't start on JBoss, it gives an Unknown Error during the deploy, and the loader doesn't disappear on the desploy.
On Websphere the application starts although it launches a few errors from configuration

It seems that although I'm destroying my ServerHttpServlet, I'm unable to destroy the Jersey servlet. Any idea on how to implement this?

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>Server</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <description></description>
        <display-name>ServerHttpServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>ServerHttpServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.transactionservice.service.ServerHttpServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <description></description>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <description></description>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>callers.REST_Application</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/jaxrs/*</url-pattern>     
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.transactionservice.service.ServerServletContext</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

**callers.REST_Application**

```
package callers;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import com.exictos.callers.DEBUG_CONFIG;
import com.exictos.log4j.LoggerCommon;

public class REST_Application extends Application
{
    private static final LoggerCommon logger = new LoggerCommon(REST_Application.class);

    public REST_Application()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses()
    {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = null;
        try
        {
            // The available REST services
            classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

            classes.add(API_CALL_REST.class);
            classes.add(API_CALL_REST_ENC.class);
            classes.add(API_CALL_CONFIG.class);
            classes.add(API_CALL_ABOUT.class);
            classes.add(DEBUG_CONFIG.class);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            logger.error("", e);
        }

        return classes;
    }
}
```

**com.transactionservice.service.ServerServletContext**

```
package com.transactionservice.service;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

import com.exictos.exception.ApplicationLoadingException;

public class ServerServletContext implements ServletContextListener
{
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent aServletContext)
    {
        //THIS IS JUST AS TEST EXAMPLE TO SEE IF WOULD WORK
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }


    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent aServletContext)
    {
        System.out.println("------------------");
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should be a little bit clearer what shutdown an application means to you: Marked as stopped in an administration tool (hard), or only take no requests (simple with a ServletFilter). But however to me it still looks harder to recognize deployment problems. Especially if you want to *reliably* recognize *all* of them

Comment: Ideally it should be marked as stopped in the administration tool, as it's currently happening with JBoss.

Answer (score 0):

Take a lookt at the [JSR-88 - Application Deployment](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr088/index.html). A WebSphere QuickStart [can be found here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Ftrun_app_jsr88.html). Note that Wildfly [removed JSR-88 support](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-527).

Programmatically stopping a deployment can also be done [with cargo](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Deployer).

I’m not really sure what you want to do but I think the normal way should be that the person or process who deployed the application should verify that the deployment worked and undeploy in the same way if not.

Answer (score 0):

Normally deployment is rolled back if something goes wrong on most of the servers. But if you still want to make sure you can just use system.exit statement in your init code.